# PEAR DataSource driver error

Tags: php, database, pear

**Situation:**

I am creating a database user interface for a client's website. I know I could simply use phpMyAdmin, but it is too complex for my client. Instead, I though I could give some of the PEAR Packages a try. After doing some research and following tutorials I decided to go with the Structures_DataGrid package. I am currently following sitepoint.com's book, 'The PHP Anthology'. It contains some great tutorials.

**Error:**

First of all, I had some difficulty installing the packages so I ended up downloading them from the PEAR website and inserting them int he server via FTP. After all that was setup, I followed the book's instructions to the last semicolon. But i get this error: Unknown DataSource driver. Please specify an existing driver. I have no idea where this error is coming from or why.

**Code:**

```
<?php

    // Include PEAR::Structures_DataGrid
    include('Structures/DataGrid.php');

    $datagrid = new Structures_DataGrid(2);
    $options = array('dsn' => 'mysql://$user:$passwords@$db_host/$db_name');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users";
    $bind = $datagrid->bind($sql, $options);
    if (PEAR::isError($bind))   {
        print('DataGrid Error: '. $bind->getMessage());
        $gridsource = '';
    } else {

        // Define our Column labels, using a 'column' => 'Label' format
        $columns = array(
            'id' => 'Id',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'last_login' => 'Last Login',
            'startDate' => 'Start Date',
            'fname' => 'First Name',
            'lname' => 'Last Name',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'cName' => 'Company',
            'cEmail' => 'Company Email',
            'cCity' => 'City',
            'cProvince' => 'Province',
            'ctr' => 'Country',
            'cSite' => 'Website'            
        );
        $datagrid->generateColumns($columns);

        // Some more options, for our renderer
        $renderer_options = array(
            'sortIconASC' => '&uArr;',
            'sortIconDESC' => '&dArr;',
            'headerAttributes' => array('bgcolor' => '#E3E3E3'),
            'evenRowAttributes' => array('bgcolor' => '#A6A6A6'),
        );
        $datagrid->setRendererOptions($renderer_options);

        // Add some final attributes to our table
        $renderer = $datagrid->getRenderer();
        $renderer->setTableAttribute('cellspacing', 0);
        $renderer->setTableAttribute('cellpadding', 5);
        $renderer->setTableAttribute('border', 1);

        // Render the table, be sure to check for errors 
        $gridbody = $datagrid->getOutput();
        if (PEAR::isError($gridbody)) {
            print('DataGrid render error: ' . $gridbody->getMessage());
            $gridbody = '';
        }

        // Finally, render the pager, again checking for errors
        $gridpager = $datagrid->getOutput(DATAGRID_RENDER_PAGER);
        if (PEAR::isError($gridpager)) {
            print('DataGrid render error: ' . $gridpager->getMessage());
            $gridpager = '';
        }
        $gridsource = $gridbody . $gridpager;
    }

?>
```

**Comments:**

All of my database credentials are correct. I am trying to connect to a MySQL database on a Unix server. I am sure I have all the required packages. I do not think that the error is here in the code. Rather it is an issue with the driver not being enabled or something like that.

**Question:**

Well, I am not sure what my question is because I am not sure what my problem is. I could ask things like 'How do I specify a driver?', 'How do I enable/activate/include a driver?' or 'Has anybody had to dealt with these issues before, and what did you do?'

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really do not have an answer, just an update.

I uninstalled everything and cleaned out the PHP directory on my server. I then downloaded the go-pear.php script and reinstalled everything.

Now everything works fine! Yay!